# mySQL, three tables: UPDATE multiple rows (each with a different value) 

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables in mySQL:

```
TABLE:CollectionAttributeValues
cID
akID
avID

TABLE: atDefault
avID
value

TABLE: CollectionVersions
cID
cvName
```

Looks Like

```
CollectionVersions
cID  cvName
1    Billete
5    Tony

atDefault
avID value
1    B.B
3    T.T

CollectionAttributeValues
cID akID avID
1   29   1
5   29   3
```

I need to take all the **values** (the column named values) in **atDefault"**
and put it into **cvName** in **CollectionVersions** 
WHERE akID = 29 in **CollectionAttributeValues**

Basically, take "Billette" and change it to "B.B". AND also take "Tony" and change it to "TT".

So far I came up with this

```
SELECT value
FROM `atDefault` AS d
LEFT JOIN `CollectionAttributeValues` AS v ON d.avID = v.avID
WHERE v.akID =29
```

But I don't know how to insert the resulting values into the "cvName" column in CollectionVersions...

Comment: What is the type of cID column?

Comment: it's not AUTO_INCREMENT in either CollectionVersions or CollectionAttributeValues. It's the primary, auto-increment in another table 'Collections'

Comment: So what should be inserted in the `cID`column of the `CollectionAttributeValues`table along with the values you get from the query you have written?

Comment: cID shouldn't change, I just need to change the value of cvNAME in all instances where akID = 29.

Comment: Answered it according to your needs. All rows in the `CollectionVersions` table would have the data that you get from the query. It would give an error if the query returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `UPDATE` all the columns of the table `CollectionVersions` with the data that you get form the query. Try the below query -

```
UPDATE CollectionVersions cv 
SET cvName = 
(SELECT value
 FROM `atDefault` AS d
 LEFT JOIN `CollectionAttributeValues` AS v ON d.avID = v.avID
 WHERE v.akID =29
 AND cv.cID = v.cID)
```

Comment: It's saying "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Your query is returning more than 1 row. How do you want this to stored in `CollectionVersions` table? If the rows are more than 1, do you want the values returned by your query comma separated and stored.

Comment: No comma separation. I added a bit more to my question, hope this clarifies a bit?

Comment: Thanks, but it still says #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: This worked! Um it also deleted some names of other files, but not quite sure why

Comment: because you ain't got a Where clause in your update... which is not what you wanted. Anyway, if it's fine for you...

Comment: So for future, is it supposed to be UPDATE...set cvName = (Select blah blah) WHERE (another join) then?